# Woocommerce: How to remove page-title at the home/shop page but not category pages

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have set the "shop" page as my front page and I want to remove the default woocommerce title from the home page of the site.
I have emptied the title but I still get an empty tag like this on the home page:

```
<h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"></h1>
```

This creates an empty area above the content which is annoying. I have tried the following solutions and they work BUT **the title page for category pages would be removed too**. I want the title only at the home page be removed.

1. First solution: I added the following code to my style:

   ```
   .woocommerce-page .page-title {

    display: none;

   }
   ```
2. Added the following to function.php

   ```
   add_filter('woocommerce_show_page_title', '__return_false');
   ```

I repeat, these solutions do what they are supposed to but I want the page-title for categories remain and only the title for the home page be removed.

Comment: beware that this filter only works, if you declare theme support. i was going nuts on why this was not working for me at all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can overwrite woocommerce template of **"archive-product.php"** into your current theme and replace with this code.

```
<?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>

            <?php if(!is_shop()) { ?>
            <h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php } ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

For reference [conditional tag of woocommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/)

**OR**

```
<?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>

                <?php if(is_product_category()) { ?>
                <h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
                <?php } ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This file is in plugins folder. Doesn't change of it defeat the purpose of creating a child theme? I mean can't I change things inside my child theme so I don't need to be worried about any updates or changes that plugins create?

Comment: yes no any defeat to plugin update when you override template into theme. reference for how to override woocommerce template file in child theme : https://v4.datafeedr.com/documentation/580

Answer (score 7):

Instead of hacking templates, you can put this in functions.php of your child theme:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', 'not_a_shop_page' );
function not_a_shop_page() {
    return boolval(!is_shop());
}
```

Comment: I don't know how....but this works!

Comment: Filter `woocommerce_show_page_title` shows page title if provided argument is `true`. The function makes argument `true` for all pages that are "not a shop page" and `false` for shop page.

Comment: Got it, but I guess I was never in a position to use  `return boolval` in WordPress to determine if I was on the shop page or not. I would argue that part should be easier for to write.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not remove the HTML `<header class="woocommerce-products-header"> </header>`

Answer (score 2):

Hello you can do this thing and i hope this work for you also

```
 <?php
    if (!is_shop()) {
      if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) {  ?>
            <h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
 <?php   }else{ ?>
      <h1 class="page-title"><?php echo ''; ?>
    }
  } ?>
```

For More [Prefer this link](http://templatetoaster.com/forum/2937/how-to-remove-page-titles-on-woocommerce-pages)

Answer (score 2):

To remove the title only from the product page you need to add this code to your css styles

```
.product-template-default .woocommerce-products-header {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Few alternate ways to do so:

1. Remove title code from your theme's home.php
2. Create a template for products page
3. For homepage, if you are using frontpage.php then it is quite easy to remove it from there. Else, you can use the last point mentioned below
4. Go to your page.php and write a simple conditional statement to check if it is a homepage or not. A reference of this conditional statement from WP codex is here

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/

Answer (score 0):

I just did this for my website, but in a more round about way.

1. I edited my archive-product.php file in the theme file editor and changed:

`<h1 class="entry-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>`

To:

`<h6 class="entry-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h6>`

2. I then edited the stylesheet page and added:

`h6 {display: none;}`

Obviously you shouldn't use this solution if you have h6 titles in your code, but for a simple solution, it does the trick.

Comment: You could just use `h6.entry-title` instead of a generic `h6` - that at least will reduce the scope of the rule.