# Woocommerce: How to remove page title from storefront theme homepage

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, title, homepage, wp-title

I have been searching online for this and everywhere I go it says to put the following into your functions.php

```
function remove_title_from_home() {
   remove_action( 'storefront_homepage', 'storefront_homepage_header', 10 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', 'remove_title_from_home' );
```

OR

```
function remove_title_from_home() {
   if ( is_front_page() ) remove_action( 'storefront_page', 'storefront_page_header', 10 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', 'remove_title_from_home' );
```

Just in case there is an update to the theme which will overwrite this as I am not using a child theme, I put them into a plugin file I created a long time ago (custom-functions.php) and all other functions I have put in there work. I have cleared WP caches and browser caches, yet neither of the suggestions above are working for me. Even though [the same is suggested at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42732242/remove-page-title-from-woocommerce-storefront-theme-homepage)

The answer here at [Removing title from page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36632/removing-title-from-page) is not good for SEO and [Woocommerce: How to remove page-title at the home/shop page but not category pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/286726/woocommerce-how-to-remove-page-title-at-the-home-shop-page-but-not-category-pag) doesn't seem to help me as the suggestions are not working for me.

The homepage content is the only page I am displaying on the front (home) page

[image]

Has there been a change to the Storefront Theme since these answers were put together or is there something I am possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'storefront_remove_title_from_home_homepage_template' );
 
function storefront_remove_title_from_home_homepage_template() {
   remove_action( 'storefront_homepage', 'storefront_homepage_header', 10 );
}
```

or if you use default template

```
add_action( 'wp', '_storefront_remove_title_from_home_default_template' );
 
function storefront_remove_title_from_home_default_template() {
   if ( is_front_page() ) remove_action( 'storefront_page', 'storefront_page_header', 10 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  So it should be `wp` instead of `woocommerce_show_page_title` in the `add_action()` function.